# How to take the average of a stochastic differential equation?

Tags: differentiation, hamiltonian, phase-space, adiabatic, stochastic-processes

I am solving a set of stochastic differential equations and I need some feedback about if what I am doing is correct.

Given a vector $\boldsymbol{C}(t)=(C_+(t),C_-(t))^T$, we can writte a set of differential equations as $\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol{C}(t)=\boldsymbol{A}(t)\boldsymbol{C}(t)$, where $\boldsymbol{A}(t)$ is a 2x2 matrix with stochastic variables. Specifically,

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{A}(t)=
\begin{pmatrix}
  -\gamma/2 -i \alpha(t)\alpha^*(t) & \alpha^*(t)\dot{\alpha}(t) \\
  \alpha(t)\dot{\alpha}^*(t) & -\gamma/2 +i \alpha(t)\alpha^*(t)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

where $\gamma>0$ and $\alpha(t)$ is a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process described by $\frac{d}{dt} \alpha(t)=-\mu \alpha(t)+\sqrt{n_{th}} \eta(t)$, such that $\overline{\eta(t)}=0$ and $\overline{\eta(t)\eta(t')}=\delta(t-t')$. Therefore, one can find that $\overline{\alpha^*(t)\alpha(t)}=n_{th}$.

I am interested in the average of $\overline{|C_{\pm}(t)|^2}=\overline{C_{\pm}(t)C^*_{\pm}(t)}$, or if it can not be done exactly, at least some flavour of it.

I would like to know if my attempted solution is correct or not, such because I am doing some risky assumptions. First, we formally integrate the set of equations

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{C}(t)=e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}(\tau)}\boldsymbol{C}(0)
\end{equation}

Then, the average I am interested can be found by the matrix elements of

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{C}(t)\boldsymbol{C}^\dagger(t)=e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}(\tau)}\boldsymbol{C}(0)\boldsymbol{C}^\dagger(0) e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}^\dagger(\tau)}
\end{equation}

While the matrix in the middle is just some coefficient, it is surrounded by stochastic integrals. So I just take the average. And this is where I make my first approximation which I think it's wrong, but I do not know better. I assume that

\begin{equation}
\overline{e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}(\tau)}\boldsymbol{C}(0)\boldsymbol{C}^\dagger(0) e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}^\dagger(\tau)}}\simeq \overline{e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}(\tau)}}\boldsymbol{C}(0)\boldsymbol{C}^\dagger(0)\overline{e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}^\dagger(\tau)}}
\end{equation}

Finally, I again do the following approximation

\begin{equation}
\overline{e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}(\tau)}}\simeq e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\overline{\boldsymbol{A}(\tau)}}
\end{equation}

And this is something I can evaluate:
\begin{equation}
\overline{\boldsymbol{A}(t)}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  -\gamma/2 -i n_{th} & -\mu n_{th} \\
   -\mu n_{th} & -\gamma/2 +i n_{th}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

where I have used $\overline{\alpha^*(t)\eta(t)}=0$ because in an Itô stochastic equation, the variable and the noise are uncorrelated.

After this, I can solve the equations for $|C_{\pm}(t)|^2$. It is, however, highly unlike that this is the correct result, as there are plenty of (unjustified) approximations.

I would appreciate it if somebody would tell me if my approximations are justified, and if not, what would be the correct approach?

PD: In case somebody wonders where that set of stochastic differential equations, they appear when one tries to solve the adiabatic theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem) where one considers the time-dependent Hamiltonian to be stochastic time-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some comments for the question that I could find, it doesn't answer everything, however it gives several elements to the question.
First of all, after a quick search on web the solution that you are proposing

$$\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol{C}(t)=\boldsymbol{A}(t)\boldsymbol{C}(t) => 
 \boldsymbol{C}(t)=e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}(\tau)}\boldsymbol{C}(0)
$$

is only valid when matrices $\boldsymbol{A}(t_1)$ and $\boldsymbol{A}(t_2)$ are commutative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion), which does not seem true for your matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$. I was trying to calculate both matrices product where $\boldsymbol{M}^{(1)} = \boldsymbol{A}(t_1) \cdot \boldsymbol{A}(t_2)$ and $\boldsymbol{M}^{(2)} = \boldsymbol{A}(t_2) \cdot \boldsymbol{A}(t_1)$ , where the matrix elements are $\beta_1 = -\gamma/2 - j \alpha(t_1) \alpha(t_2)$, $ \varsigma_1 = \alpha(t_1)\alpha^*(t_1)$.

I get that

$$ \boldsymbol{M}^{(1)} = \begin{pmatrix}
 \beta_1 \beta_2 + \varsigma_1\varsigma^*_2       & \beta_1 \varsigma_2 + \varsigma_1 \beta_2^*    \\
 \varsigma_1^* \beta_2  +  \beta_1^*\varsigma^*_2 & \varsigma^*_1\varsigma_2 + \beta^*_1 \beta^*_2
\end{pmatrix} $$

$$ \boldsymbol{M}^{(2)} = \begin{pmatrix}
 \beta_2 \beta_1 + \varsigma_2\varsigma^*_1       & \beta_2 \varsigma_1 + \varsigma_2 \beta_1^*    \\
 \varsigma_2^* \beta_1  +  \beta_2^*\varsigma^*_1 & \varsigma^*_1\varsigma_2 + \beta^*_1 \beta^*_2
\end{pmatrix} $$

So in order for $\boldsymbol{M}^{(1)} = \boldsymbol{M}^{(2)}$, first you need to have $\varsigma = \varsigma^*$, so the diagonal elements are equal for both matrices. However, for non-diagonal elements, it is not true, if I am not mistaken.

Secondly, I am not sure that anything below really useful for the answer since  the previous solution might be not true, anyway following our discusssion at \https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731730/expectation-value-of-stochastic-differential-equation-using-fokker-planck-distri  the time average and expected value is not the same, thus you can calculate the expected value as $E\{\int A \mathrm{d}t \} = \int E\{A\} \mathrm{d}t$, since the integral is a Rieman sum and you can perform this operation on every term.

Next, I would not agree that $\overline{\alpha^*(t)\alpha(t)}=n_{th}$, it is more likely  $\overline{\alpha^*(t)\alpha(t)}=\frac{n_{th}} {2 \mu}$. It is prooved from the fact that, calculating with a transfert function of the noise equation, first multiplying the PSD of the $S_{\alpha} =S_{\eta}(\omega) \cdot |T|^2$. And than calculating

$$R_{\alpha}(0) = \int\limits^\infty_{\infty} S_\alpha(f) \mathrm{d}f =  \int\limits^\infty_{\infty} S_\eta(f) \frac{n_{th}}{ \omega^2 + \mu^2}\mathrm{d}f = \int\limits^\infty_{\infty} 1 \frac{n_{th}}{ \omega^2 + \mu^2}\mathrm{d}f = \frac{n_{th}}{2 \mu}$$

By the way do you assume that the homogeneous solution of the equation tends to zero? Otherwise the stochastic process $\alpha$ is not stationary and its autocorrelation depends on two time variables.

If the process is stationary the random variables $\alpha(t)$ and $\dot{\alpha}(t)$ are uncorrelated. So already $E\{\alpha(t)\dot{\alpha}(t)\} =E\{\alpha(t)\dot{\alpha}(t)\} = 0$. It is true for real process, I am guessing it should be similar for complex process, however I cannot prove that.

The last thing, I am not agree that $\overline{\alpha^*(t)\eta(t)}=0$ because the variable and the noise are uncorrelated, on the contrary, intuitively future $\alpha(t')$ depends on previous $\eta(t)$, since there is an equation for both processees. It can be seen from the correlation of both variables
$$R_{\eta \alpha } = E \{ \eta(t) \alpha^*(t+\tau) \} = R_{\eta \eta}(\tau) \otimes h^*(-\tau) = \delta (\tau) \otimes h^*(-\tau) = h^*(-\tau)$$
, where $h(t)$ is an impulse response function, which is the inverse Fourier transform of the transfer function of the "noise" equation $T(\omega) = \frac{1}{j \omega+ \mu}$, thus $h(t) = e^{-\mu t} H(t)$, where $H(t)$ is a Heaviside function. So the correlation of the variables $R_{\eta \alpha } (\tau) =e^{\mu \tau} H(-\tau) $, so, as I said the function $\alpha (t- \tau))$ indeed depends on $\eta(t)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, both here and in the other post. I spend these days learning how to solve these problems and I just realized how hard it can be. Here, for example, you are right and I cannot even formally integrate due to the non-commutativity of the matrices, I did not realize it. Another issue is with the correlations between the $\alpha^*(t) \eta(t)$. I thought I was working with the Itô formalism, where they decouple, but this is not true, so you are right I still need to evaluate those terms. Thank you again for your comments, really illustrative for me. I'll keep working.

Comment: Ok, happy to help. The transfer function formalism is a very powerful function for stochastic equations. As for Itô formalism, where do you get some information? I am just interested in that myself.

Comment: Do you happen to know any nice review on this transfer function formalism for stochastic equations? As per Itô formalism, my source is Quantum Noise by Gardiner and Zoller. It has a really nice physically-motivated introduction to stochastic differential equations.

Comment: Sorry do not know small reviews on that. There might be some books on electronics that treat stochastic processes with transfer function